# Output of "helm list --all" is empty

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have deployed jupyterhub on my GKE cluster using helm. However, when I run `helm list --all` (or `helm list --failed` etc) I see no output.

I can confirm that tiller is running in my cluster:

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0", GitCommit:"2e55dbe1fdb5fdb96b75ff144a339489417b146b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0", GitCommit:"2e55dbe1fdb5fdb96b75ff144a339489417b146b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

And I can see the tiller pod:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep tiller
tiller-deploy-778f674bf5-5jksm                                   1/1     Running   0          132d
```

I can also see that my deployment of jupyterhub is running using `kubectl get pods -n jhub`.

How I can I determine why the output of `helm list` is empty?

Comment: What do the logs for tiller say ? What serviceAccount did you use to deploy tiller ? And what Role/RoleBindings did you set ? Can you provide this info ?

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue where `helm list` was showing empty output.

In case if anyone lands on this page looking for solution, please check below.
source (similar) : https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7146

In short : Issue here we need to use namespaces when we do listing. or --all-namespace would help as well.

```
helm list --all-namespaces
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling you are missing some permissions. This is a GKE cluster. So RBAC is enabled.

The standard practice is to first create a dedicated Service account in the appropriate namespace. For example sake, lets say `kube-system`

```
kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system
```

Then you need to give appropriate permissions to this service account.

**FOR TESTING / NON-SECURE !!!**

Lets allow this service account to run with super user privileges i.e. run as `cluster-admin`

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
```

**FOR PRODUCTION / SECURE**

Create a Role that gives the minimum privileges for tiller to run and associate with the `tiller` service account using a RoleBinding.

Then go ahead and initialize tiller with the associated serviceAccount.

```
helm init --service-account tiller
```

Comment: $ helm init --service-account tiller
Error: unknown command "init" for "helm"

Did you mean this?
        lint

Run 'helm --help' for usage.